# Read a string stored in a resource file (resx) with dynamic file name

Tags: c#, dynamic, resources

In my C# application I need to create a .resx file of strings customized for every customer.

What I want to do is avoid recompiling the entire project every time I have to provide my application to my customer, so I need to dynamic access to this string.
So, how can I access (during the app execution) to a resx file if I kwow the file name only on the execution time?

Since now I write something similar:

```
Properties.Resources.MyString1
```

where Resource is my Resource.resx file.
But I need something like this:

```
GetStringFromDynamicResourceFile("MyFile.resx", "MyString1");
```

Is it possible?

Thanks
Mark

Comment: Ok Prashanth it wors!
The only thing is that "Func" method cannot be "static" otherwise compiler throw an exception..

Thanks to all...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Will something like this help in your case?

```
Dictionary<string, string> resourceMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public static void Func(string fileName)
{
    ResXResourceReader rsxr = new ResXResourceReader(fileName);        
    foreach (DictionaryEntry d in rsxr)
    {
        resourceMap.Add(d.Key.ToString(),d.Value.ToString());           
    }        
    rsxr.Close();
}

public string GetResource(string resourceId)
{
    return resourceMap[resourceId];
}
```

Comment: It is better to wrap ResXResourceReader into **using** statement, instead of explicitly closing reader.

Comment: I think I chanced across the code here (walkthrough 2): http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yougerthen/105262008135822PM/1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You could put the needed resources into a separate DLL (one for each customer), then extract the resources dynamically using Reflection:

```
Assembly ass = Assembly.LoadFromFile("customer1.dll");
string s = ass.GetManifestResource("string1");
```

I may have the syntax wrong - it's early.  One potential caveat here:  accessing a DLL through Reflection will lock the DLL file for a length of time, which may block you from updating or replacing the DLL on the client's machine.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible. You need to read about [ResouceSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourceset.aspx) class in msdn. And if you want to load .resx files directly, you can use [ResxResourceSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourceset.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use [LINQ to SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386976(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of referencing [System.Windows.Forms.ResXResourceReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resxresourcereader(v=vs.110).aspx) class in your project.

```
public string GetStringFromDynamicResourceFile(string resxFileName, string resource)
{
    return XDocument
                .Load(resxFileName)
                .Descendants()
                .FirstOrDefault(_ => _.Attributes().Any(a => a.Value == resource))?
                .Value;
}
```

And use it:

```
GetStringFromDynamicResourceFile("MyFile.resx", "MyString1");
```